# If I use hooks that updates like useContext, would it make it NOT a candidate for React.memo()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

For obviously pure components like

```
function DefinitelyPure({label}:{label:string}) {
  return <View><Text>{label</Text></View>
}
```

I know I can safely make this memoized as

```
const DefinitelyPure= React.memo(function ({label}:{label:string}) {
  return <View><Text>{label</Text></View>
});
DefinitelyPure.displayName = "DefinitelyPure";
```

However, what if I have something like

```
function DefinitelyPure({label}:{label:string}) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return <View style={{backgroundColor: theme.primary.backgroundColor}}><Text>{label</Text></View>
}
```

where `useTheme()` can change when the user switches themes in the app.  Would the memoized component know to rerender when the context changes? (I am thinking no)

I am only asking for `useContext`, since that one should trigger a rerender when the context changes and it's on the top level, and not other hooks like `useState`

Comment: `Would the memoized component know to rerender when the context changes?` Yes. React.memo only stops renders caused by prop changes. State and context can still cause a rerender.

Comment: So react memo on components that useContext and useState is still ok to do then?

Comment: Usually there is no need to use `memo`. I would use `memo` only if rendering the component causes performance issues

Comment: `So react memo on components that useContext and useState is still ok to do then?` Yes

Comment: @Ni can you make it into an answer?